# enable textbox with checkbox checked with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

HEllo - 
I am trying to enable/disable textbox when checkbox is checked (enable) or unchecked (disable). 
WIth the piece of code i have nothing is happening once the checkbox is checked/unchecked. 
Here is what I have:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AssociationInfo.ascx.cs" Inherits="Administration.Modules.AssociationInfo" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function enableTextBox() {
            window.onload = function () {
                var check = document.getElementById("chkAssociation");
                check.onchange = function () {
                    if (this.checked == true)
                        document.getElementById("txtAddress").disabled = false;
                    else
                        document.getElementById("txtAddress").disabled = true;
                };
            };
        }
    </script>

    <div>
    <h2>Association Info</h2>
    <br />

      <asp:CheckBox Checked="false" ID="chkAssociation" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" Text="Test" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

The code is in web user control. Could that be reason why is not working correctly?

Thanks for helping

Thanks everyone for the help in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "onclick" instead of "onchange" - I believe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but still nothing is happening. I am having the code in web user control, I don't know if that can be one of the reasons. However, I edited my code above with the complete web user control, if you guys can see some mistake. Thanks for helping

Comment: Inside a user control, the ID of the rendered control is not the same as the ID you give it. Take a look at the "view source" in your browser, and you'll see your txtAddress is now named something like "ctrl_00_txtAddress" or something like that.  You'll need to do what adatapost did in his answer, wrapping the call in a <%=txtAddress.ClientID %> block, to make the javascript work.

Comment: By the way, the same holds true for master pages, which most sites these days are using - so it's always a good idea to use the "ClientID" syntax every time you reference a server control using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I can select both of your answers for correct, but both of you helped me. Have a nice day

Answer (score 4):

Please turn of AutoPostBack.

```
<asp:CheckBox Checked="false" 
              OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" 
              ID="chkAssociation" 
              runat="server" />
```

EDIT: Try this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var check = document.getElementById("<%=chkAssociation.ClientID %>");
            check.onchange = function() {
                if (this.checked == true)
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtAddress.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
                else
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtAddress.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
            };
        };
</script>        

<asp:CheckBox  Checked="false"   ID="chkAssociation" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" Enabled="false" Text="Test" runat="server" />
```

Comment: firefox. But I tried also IE and Chrome, with the solution you proposed and still nothing is happening.The code is in web user control not in .aspx page.

Comment: Have a look at post. I've changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this**

**1.If Checkbox is Checked then the Textbox be Disable**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
{
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = bEnable

}
</script>


 <asp:TextBox ID="t1" Text="" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" Checked="false" onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 't1');" runat="server" />
```

**2.If Checkbox is Checked then  the Textbox be Enable**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
{
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable

}
</script>
        <asp:TextBox ID="t1" Text="" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" Checked="true" onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 't1');" runat="server" />
```